# HP laptop - DVD boot difficulties

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, uefi

Yesterday, I bought an HP ProBook 4330s. It had Linux on it.
I tried to use a bootable Windows DVD to reinstall the system but it didn't work. I changed the priority in BIOS, the CD/DVD is first on the list. I also disabled *Fast Boot*, and enabled UEFI. But it always boots from the hard drive.

I noticed that after pressing **F9** there are some boot devices to choose from but no CD/DVD.
People write about disabling *Safe Boot*. I have been searching for it in my BIOS the whole night but it is not there for sure...

Anyways I used some tool in BIOS to remove everything from hard disc.
Now, it's not booting anything and pressing any button gives me advanced system diagnostic.
Only BIOS opens under **F10**.

Any ideas how to install the system?

Answer (score 1):

I think the UEFI is getting in the way, disable the UEFI to enable legacy devices, then use the F9 key for advanced boot options, the DVD should be there.